# Switch to side arm or reload?

Tags: natural-selection-2

When you have a skulk or other alien on top of you at point blank range and you just spent your last lmg bullet, is it better to try and get some space and reload or switch to pistol?

Is it situational?

Comment: If it's Onos, reload and hope for the best. Anything else switch to your sidearm - it deals heavy damage and has a decent sized clip. There's enough firepower to even take down a Fade if you are accurate enough with both your lmg and pistol.

Comment: This is true I took down a fade with lmg spray and then 5 accurte pistol hits.  Pistol actually has really high damage but it is difficult to hit with it.  Sometimes I even prefer it over lmg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're alone, and the skulk is either already in melee range or rapidly advancing, your best bet is to switch to your pistol.

Even the slowest alien life forms can outrun a marine, so once the enemy is on top of you, your range advantage is *gone* and you aren't going to get it back.

Jumping around does make you harder to bite, but this is mainly because a good skulk will *also* be jumping around trying to be harder to shoot. As soon as your foe realizes that you're reloading your LMG instead of shooting back with a pistol, though, they'll just calmly chomp your leg off.

The answer gets more complicated when you have a buddy with you. In this situation, your priority is just to *stay alive* and buy time for your partner to kill the skulk themselves. In this situation, the skulk still has to make themselves hard to hit, so there's a chance you'll have time to reload your LMG while bunny hopping, but if your partner is also on an empty clip you'll be in trouble.

Generally speaking though, always switch to the pistol. **Damage now** will keep you alive more often then **damage 3 seconds from now**.